# What's the proper cable to connect this power station to a solar panel?

Tags: electrical, solar-panels, solar, power-backup

My uncle gave me his old 1000w portable power station. I already have a Bluetti SP120 portable solar panel that has mc4 connectors. I'd like to use this to the power station. I tried googling it to no avail. I also tried google lens and it didn't yield any meaningful result.

Here's a photo of the port that the power station has that'll accept solar:

[image]

here's the spec sheet if it helps:

[image]

another picture for reference:

[image]

Comment: Looks like an old mil-spec connector - is the outside threaded to screw the connector down? If the company still exists they may have cords to connect.

Comment: Go to, say, Mouser (or your regional equivalent) and search on ‘2 pin mil spec plug’…

Comment: I also tried asking, do you think it's gx16 aviation socket?

Comment: Conceivable, but I don’t see the notch for polarity. Plenty of drawings on line with dimensions. What I see rates them at only 7 amps which might be a little low depending on the panel.

Answer (score 2):

guys i've finally found it locally.. thank you for those who helped! it cost about $2.50

[image]